# Pulling WordPress Featured Images using Aggregator to Display Them

Tags: 7, feeds

I'm using Drupal 7's Feed Aggregator to pull WordPress posts. I have a block with a view displaying these posts (3 of the most current rss feed items). My question is how can I pick-up WordPress's featured image of a post to display as a thumbnail of the Drupal RSS item?

I have edited the RSS Settings to include the  HTML tag to the list, but it only pulls images inside of a post, rather than a featured image of a post.

Is there a way to achieve this using the RSS Aggregation module?

Conversely, on the WordPress website I'm using [this plugin](http://web-argument.com/2008/11/09/wp-rss-images-wordpress-plugin/) to add featured images to the RSS feed and looking at the feed XML, is it displaying the featured images as well as post images.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Wow, this question is old. For anyone else in a similar situation, try https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_imagegrabber